# app engine response size varies

Tags: ios, iphone, google-app-engine

I have build a number of REST interfaces in app engine and while debugging a request on my iPhone client and via Chrome, I noticed that two identical requests had different responses sizes:

- `"GET /card?omid=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 1468 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36"`
- `"GET /card?omid=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 10669 - "Null Society 1.83 (iPhone; iPhone OS 6.1.3; en_US)"`

Note that the identical request from the iPhone client is 7x larger than the one from Chrome. These requests were a minute apart, and my server-side code does not distinguish between clients for determining responses. In this particular request, the server merely reads the query variable, "omid", and returns the appropriate data.

The only thing I can think of is that app engine natively compresses data by client? Seems weird though. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `response` section of the GAE docs it notes:

> If the client sends HTTP headers with the request indicating that the
>   client can accept compressed (gzipped) content, **App Engine compresses
>   the response data automatically** and attaches the appropriate response
>   headers. It uses both the Accept-Encoding and User-Agent request
>   headers to determine if the client can reliably receive compressed
>   responses. Custom clients can indicate that they are able to receive
>   compressed responses by specifying both Accept-Encoding and User-Agent
>   headers with a value of gzip.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/#Python_Responses

That sounds like it could explain what you are seeing.

Comment: Great catch! Now I'll check if I can have my iPhone client send those headers. The bandwidth savings would be amazing. Thanks!